# how to handle transport.Sanitization() while working with multiple namspaces in Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, nservicebus, azureservicebus

I'm using multiple namespace partitioning

```
var routing = transport.NamespacePartitioning();
routing.UseStrategy<RoundRobinNamespacePartitioning>();
routing.AddNamespace(name: "primary", connectionString: xyz);
routing.AddNamespace(name: "Secondary",connectionString: xy);
```

So need help while creating subscription in both the namespaces

Comment: I'm going to tag this as NServiceBus question, as it's not Azure Service Bus specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a chance to review the [documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/azure-service-bus/sanitization) on the topic? It goes into details how everything works.

Also, there's a [sample](https://docs.particular.net/samples/azure/custom-sanitization-asb/) that provides a working solution you can download and run. It shows how to sanitize events, just like you're asking.

Sanitization will work on all namespaces you're going to use (depending on the partitioning strategy).

Comment: its throwing error 
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. TrackingId:xyz, SystemTracker:[service bus name].[topic]/Subscriptions/SubscriptionsName, Timestamp:01/02/2017 06:24:32

Comment: What's throwing an error? The sample or your code? TrackingID can be used with azure support team and usually indicates a problem. Without details can't help :)